# After upgrading from jdk1.5 to jdk1.7 Spring beans are not getting depoloyed on JBOSS 4.0.3

Tags: java, spring, aop

Currently we are using jdk1.5, spring 2.0.4. We are using many libraries like aspectj, cxf, etc.. We are Deploying our application on JBOSS 4.0.3.
We are upgrading jdk1.5 to 1.7. I am able to compile the code successfully. However when I am deploying the application. I am getting below error.

> 2013-09-03 12:47:50,112 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader [main] 200  ContextLoader.java                  ERROR  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logInbound' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rclTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rclTransactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-rclDao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rclSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rclSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-rclDao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-resources.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut executingErrorManageableMethod
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rclTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rclTransactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-rclDao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rclSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rclSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-rclDao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-resources.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut executingErrorManageableMethod

After googling a lot I have updated our 3rdparty libraries like cxf version 2.6.3 and neethi version 3.0.0. I have started getting below error when I am deploying the ear file.

> 2013-09-03 22:11:54,518 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader [main] 227  ContextLoader.java                  ERROR  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-resources.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logInbound' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logInbound' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-rclWebservices.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut executingErrorManageableMethod
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:451)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)

After this I have updated my spring jars to 2.5.3. I am still getting below error.

> 2013-09-17 12:23:25,054 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader [main] 227  ContextLoader.java                  ERROR  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-resources.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'logInbound' while setting bean property 'inInterceptors' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logInbound' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-rclWebservices.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut executingErrorManageableMethod
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:451)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)

Can anybody advice what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that JBOSS 4.0.3 uses new JDK version to get up and running.

Comment: We have another application which is also upgraded from jdk1.5 to jdk1.7. It is getting deployed on jboss 4.0.3.successfully. However in that application spring is not used.